# Mismatch while saving OffsetTime in timez

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

In spring-boot I am trying to save an OffsetTime value in the timetz column in Postgres.

When I'm saving 03:00-07:00, its getting saved as 03:00-08:00. Any idea why? or how to debug this?

Comment: 1) There is no `timez` type in Postgres there is `time with time zone` 2) This question needs more information a) Postgres version. b) What does `SHOW timezone` return? c) What is the code you are using to save the data? d) What is the time zone of the client you are running the code in? **Add this information as text update to your question**.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

> PostgreSQL endeavors to be compatible with the SQL standard
> definitions for typical usage. However, the SQL standard has an odd
> mix of date and time types and capabilities. Two obvious problems are:
>
> - Although the date type cannot have an associated time zone, the time
>   type can. Time zones in the real world have little meaning unless
>   associated with a date as well as a time, since the offset can vary
>   through the year with daylight-saving time boundaries.
> - The default time zone is specified as a constant numeric offset from
>   UTC. It is therefore impossible to adapt to daylight-saving time when
>   doing date/time arithmetic across DST boundaries.
>
> To address these difficulties, we recommend using date/time types that
> contain both date and time when using time zones. **We do not recommend
> using the type time with time zone** (though it is supported by
> PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL
> standard). **PostgreSQL assumes your local time zone for any type
> containing only date or time.**